# connecting from the backend to fetch all surveys in my account

Tags: surveymonkey

I need to do all my actions on the back-end, no browser.
In the documentation I see I need the following values to get the `Authorization: bearer ????????` value.

```
curl -i -X POST https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/token -d \
"client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET \
&code=AUTH_CODE \
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI \
&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID \
&grant_type=authorization_code"
```

I am not building an app, I just want to connect to my account to fetch all surveys.
Where do I get the values for:
**YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET**
**AUTH_CODE**
**YOUR_CLIENT_ID**

What do I put in **YOUR_REDIRECT_URI** as there is no such thing in back-end actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need an application created in order to get an access token. There is an undocumented method for backend API access (for the app owner) using the grant type `client_credentials`.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/token \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_secret=<secret>&client_id=<client_id>&grant_type=client_credentials'
```

This should work for getting access to your own account.

With regards to the app, you can leave the redirect URI alone. Note if you go to the settings page of your app, it also provides you with an access token to use, but I would advise using the above flow as a way to handle tokens being revoked or expired in the future.

Comment: this is not working, I copied that string and replaced it with the values from my app setting, I get 401 (wrong client id or secret).

Comment: I do get the api to work with the access token (I point this to show I have no error in using curl).

Comment: I made an edit, I think you probably need the content type but tested that and it worked for me

Comment: Works thank you. Can u add this to your documentation.Can I suggest changing the error message to reflect the real problem.