# Setting up SurveyMonkey API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, config, surveymonkey

I am fairly new to all the OAuth stuff. I did a Facebook OAuth a while back but found it very confusing, although I ultimately made it work.

I have a Rails/React app that I would like to plug into the Survey Monkey API. Specifically, I want to create surveys in the Survey Monkey dashboard, and then make `GET` requests to get all that info, then use it to populate my own forms, bundle them up into a `POST` and send em back to Survey Monkey.

Seems simple, but I don't know where to begin! I created a Public App, which gave me my `Client_ID` and `Secret_ID`.

I guess my question is, literally first step here, where do I begin? Where am I supposed to put the `client` and `secret` id's? Also, I am assuming that other than setting up something, I *think*, in the `config` folder, I just make all my API calls in my controller and probably don't need additional files or folder.

Again, I just need real barebones starting block type advice here. If someone wouldn't mind, it would be a really big help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for the rails part, but for OAuth with SurveyMonkey the instructions are available [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#authentication).

Basically, with your client ID and client secret, you'll also need to set a redirect uri (a route in your app, say `/surveymonkey/oauth` to send a `code` to that you can use to exchange for an access token.

So when you want to get access to a user's SurveyMonkey account, you will somewhere in your app send them to:

```
https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/authorize?client_id=<your_client_id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>
```

This will show them the SurveyMonkey OAuth page for your app, when the user clicks "Authorize" we will send them back to your redirect URI that you set with the code, something like:

```
https://example.com/surveymonkey/oauth?code=<oauth_code>
```

Your view pulls the code from the GET parameter then you can exchange that code for a long lived access token that you would store somewhere:

```
POST https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_secret=<your_secret> \
&code=<auth_code_you_just_got> \
&redirect_uri=<same_redirect_uri_as_before> \
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

You can then make API calls to SurveyMonkey by adding the header `Authorization: bearer <access_token>` to your API calls to `api.surveymonkey.net/v3/*` and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The way we are going to use it, it's as if I am the only OAuth user, making calls to and from the Survey Monkey API on behalf of my users. My users are supplying the answers, and I am supplying the questions/surveys. As far as SurveyMonkey is concerned, I am the only User here..._i think_.

Comment: If you are only accessing the same account as the app owner then you are probably creating a `private` application. In which case you can just use the access token provided in the settings page or better to be safe see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46899079/913139 on how to pull tokens just for your own account.

Comment: Oh, cool. I just assumed initially that we would use a Public app, given the cap on API calls with Private among others. You think in this use case, that private would make most sense here? Because, like I said, we are interacting, via API calls, with our own SM dashboard and surveys, it's just that we're adding user provided data. Also, I found this gem that looks promising. It's a Monkey Strategy https://github.com/techvalidate/omniauth-surveymonkey

Comment: omniauth-surveymonkey seems like a good choice, you can use that if it works for you. Public apps require you to publish your app in our app directory and allow it to be used bay any SM user. If that's not your end goal then you should be a private app. See the FAQ https://developer.surveymonkey.com/faq/

Comment: Great. Looks like Private is the way to go then. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

You should look to `omniauth` or a similar gem to help you all things oAuth. There is no existing [strategy](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies) for Survey Monkey, but you can probably get a good start seeing how those strategies are implemented.

Bonus points if you can extract an OmniAuth strategy for Survey Monkey.

Comment: > an OmniAuth strategy for Survey Monkey.


This exists [here](https://github.com/techvalidate/omniauth-surveymonkey), matey.